# UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion on Linux

Tags: c++, utf-8, char, utf-16, wchar-t

This is the way we are currently converting a UTF-16 to UTF-8 on Ubuntu 18.04.

The input is a `const wchar_t*` (UTF-16) and the output is a `const char*` (UTF-8):

```
const char* to_string(const wchar_t* input) 
{
    std::wstring w(input);
    std::string s(w.begin(), w.end());
    return strdup(s.c_str());
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working because I'm still seeing non UTF-8 encoded characters in my string. Example:

> Adobe® Flash® Player

Is there a problem with the `to_string` function above?

Comment: This doesn't really convert anything, it just casts every `wchar_t` to a `char`. It only works correctly for plain 7-bit ASCII characters. For one thing, you'd always end up with `s.size() == w.size()`, when clearly a UTF-8 sequence may sometimes need to be longer (when counted in octets) than the equivalent UTF-16 sequence (when counted in 16-bit code points).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the response. Do you have an idea or code snippet how I could update the function above? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: See if the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) helps.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of another question, because the other asks specifically for code that does not rely on a particular OS.  If that's not sufficient for your question please let me know.